# Chinese characters(?) on very cool piece of old art

Tags: translation

I’m not even entirely sure this is Chinese versus Japanese. But I’ve come into possession of a massive (11x5 ft) piece of Asian art, and would like to translate the calligraphy as I suspect it relates to the landscape/scene that is portrayed in the picture. See image below and thanks for any help!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The characters from right to left read "**蓬萊仙境**" - the island of immortals.

Comment: That’s 青島「貝」雕 (shell engraving)

Comment: @dROOOze You are correct. Thanks.